# How to obtain user's current visiting country location in .NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have gone through so many documents but nothing is working out for me. I have followed  [a link](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Find-Visitors-Geographic-Location-GeoLocation-using-IP-Address-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx)

I want to get current user's location by IP address. But, my `ipAddress` always shows  `null` and then `::1`. I do not know what am I doing wrong.

Anyone can please help me to overcome this problem.

Model

```
   public class LocationModel
    {
        public string IP { get; set; }
        public string Country_Code { get; set; }           

    }
```

Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string ipAddress = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
        {
            ipAddress = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        }
        LocationModel location = new LocationModel();
        string url = string.Format("http://freegeoip.net/json/{0}", ipAddress);
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            string json = client.DownloadString(url);
            location = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<LocationModel>(json);
        }

        return View(location);
    }
}
```

View

```
@model IPAddress_Location_MVC.Models.LocationModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr><td>IP</td><td>@Model.IP</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Country Code</td><td>@Model.Country_Code</td></tr>           
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Nilesh pointed out; the response you are getting is valid. ::1 is the short notation for the IPv6 loopback address. This is the equivalent of the IPv4 127.0.0.0 or Localhost. **Since you are running it locally and connecting locally it is reporting your Localhost address.** If you would run this code on a different machine then your own, and would connect to it from your own machine, you would get a 'real' ip returned.

The second point you mentioned is you get 'The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.' when calling the FreeGeoIP service is caused because that endpoint no longer is in use. (Just surf to that URL: http://freegeoip.net/json/) To be complete, it returns this message:

> IMPORTANT - PLEASE UPDATE YOUR API ENDPOINT This API endpoint is
>   deprecated and has now been shut down. To keep using the freegeoip
>   API, please update your integration to use the new ipstack API
>   endpoint, designed as a simple drop-in replacement. You will be
>   required to create an account at https://ipstack.com and obtain an API
>   access key. For more information on how to upgrade please visit our
>   Github Tutorial at: https://github.com/apilayer/freegeoip#readme

**Update:**

The new API is formatted as:

> http://api.ipstack.com/IP_FOR_LOOKUP?access_key=YOUR_ACCESS_KEY&output=json&legacy=1

In order to read the result (Json) you could use a Json deserializer like NewtonSoft. You need to reference the Newtonsoft.Json package in your project and create a POCO that represents the result. Then call Newtonsoft to deserialize the Json as your object. For an example you can check [their documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm).

Comment: I have updated `url` path using  `ipstack` like this `string url = string.Format("http://api.ipstack.com/" +"?"+ipAddress+"access_key=65a3de6353cbf40792a59");`. I am not sure whether this is correct way. Another question, how to get country code by using json now. please help me.

Comment: According to their GitHub readme it should be in this format (for Json): `http://api.ipstack.com/186.116.207.169?access_key=YOUR_ACCESS_KEY&output=json&legacy=1`
In order to map the Json back to a C# object you can use NewtonSoft.Json: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried getting the IP Address like this?

```
string ipAddress =  HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

I found this [here](https://lukencode.com/2010/05/19/ip-to-geo-location-in-asp-net-mvc/)

Comment: `Connection` is giving me error. `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'HttpContextBase' does not contain a definition for 'Connection' and no extension method 'Connection' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpContextBase' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) IPAddress_Location_MVC C:\Users\Rajesh\Downloads\IPAddress_Location_MVC\IPAddress_Location_MVC\Controllers\HomeController.cs 20 Active`

Comment: I tried that as well but getting `::1`. Not working as expected. Please suggest.

Comment: @MVC you are getting `::1` because of the code running in localhost. Try to host it on your local IIS server you will get the IP address of your LAN and if hosted on actual server you will get the IP address

Comment: @Nilesh, How to host it on local IIS server. And also giving error near `string json = client.DownloadString(url);` `System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.'`

Comment: URL `http://freegeoip.net/json` is deprecated now check below link for hosting on local IIS http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/1247/how-to-host-aspnet-application-on-the-web-server-iis

Comment: @Nilesh, Thank you. One more small help. As you mentioned `http://freegeoip.net/json` is deprecated so if i use `ipstack` like this  `string url = string.Format("http://api.ipstack.com/" +"?"+ipAddress+"access_key=65a3de6353cbf40792a59");` then how can i retrieve `country_code` using model. Please guide me and if possible then can you please answer this. I have spent the whole day researching onto this. Please help me. Thank you.